# How do I pass information between react-js components without re-rendering?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, antd

I have a page with two relevant components on it: a tree decomposition graph and a details pane:

[screenshot of components](https://i.stack.imgur.com/og5dh.png)

The user should be able to click on a node of the the graph, which will fire an onClick event to set nodeDetails, which is a React state hook. The details pane takes nodeDetails as a prop and uses the node_id and classification to query a database and retrieve information about that node, which it displays on the right.

Both the graph (a DecompositionTreeGraph from ant-design-charts) and the details pane are children of <MyGraph/>, which is structured as such:

```
...
const Graph = memo(function Graph() {
    if(!baseGraphData)
      {
        return(
          <div style = {{display: "flex",
            alignItems: "center",
            justifyContent: "center",
            height: "100%",
            width: "100%"}}>
          Loading...
          </div>
        );
      }
      else{
      plotRef = <DecompositionTreeGraph {...config}/> //config contains the onClick event
        return(
        plotRef
        );
      }
    })


return(
<Stack direction={"row"} justifyContent={"space-between"}>
        <Card variant='outlined' sx = {{height: "80vh", width: "49vw"}} >
          <CardContent  sx ={{height: "100%", width: "100%"}}>
            {/* Graph interface */}
            <Graph/>                  
          </CardContent>
        </Card>
        <Stack direction={"column"} justifyContent={"space-between"}>
          <Card variant='outlined' sx = {{height: "80vh", width: "49vw"}} >
          <CardContent sx ={{height: "100%", width: "100%"}}>
            <form onSubmit={handleSearch}>                   
            {/* Search field */}
            <TextField 
              margin="dense"
              name="searchFilter"
              label="Search the graph"
              fullWidth
              defaultValue={searchFilter}
              InputProps={{
              endAdornment:
                <InputAdornment position="end"> 
                    <IconButton type="submit">
                      <SearchRoundedIcon/>
                    </IconButton>
                </InputAdornment>
              }}
              /> 
              </form>
              &nbsp;
              <Divider/>
              &nbsp;
              {/* Details pane */}
              <GraphDetailDisplay 
              object_name={nodeDetails.node_id}
              object_classification={nodeDetails.node_classification}/>
            </CardContent>
          </Card>
        </Stack>
      </Stack>
)
```

My problem is that when I set nodeDetails, the state change causes a re-render of the whole tree including the graph display itself, thus resetting the level of zoom and the view position. I have tried to stop re-rendering my wrapping it in a memo, but this hasn't worked, and I have tried various iterations of useMemo.

So am I missing something fundamental here? All I need is for <GraphDetailDisplay> to read two variables from <Graph> without the latter re-rendering. Is this a bad pattern for React? How can I implement this functionality using memos and states or otherwise?